# Why does this MDN example use `undefined` in `.bind(undefined, 37)`?

Tags: javascript, function-binding

One of the uses of `Function.prototype.bind`, according to [MDN](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Function/bind):

> The next simplest use of `bind()` is to make a function with
> pre-specified initial arguments. These arguments (if any) follow the
> provided `this` value and are then inserted at the start of the
> arguments passed to the target function, followed by the arguments
> passed to the bound function, whenever the bound function is called.

Question: Why is `undefined` being bound here? It should be the `this` value which should have been sent. If the same is happening here, how is `undefined` an object?

```js
function list() {
  return Array.prototype.slice.call(arguments);
}

var list1 = list(1, 2, 3); // [1, 2, 3]

// Create a function with a preset leading argument.
var leadingThirtysevenList = list.bind(undefined, 37);

var list2 = leadingThirtysevenList(); // [37]
var list3 = leadingThirtysevenList(1, 2, 3); // [37, 1, 2, 3]
```

Comment: Because `this` inside the `list` is not used, so anything can be passed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> Why is `undefined` being bound here?

Because the value of `this` inside `list` doesn't matter (because `list` doesn't ever reference `this`) but you have to specify argument 0 as *something* in order to specify argument 1. In other words, you cannot skip positional arguments.

> how is `undefined` an object?

It isn’t. In [strict mode](https://developer.mozilla.org/en/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Strict_mode), the `this` value can be specified as any value — object or primitive, including `undefined`. Outside of strict mode, non-nullish primitives are coerced to objects, i.e. primitives other than `null` and `undefined` are wrapped as an object. If `null` or `undefined` are specified, `this` will default to the global object (`window` in browsers).

Comment: Got the first part, and that clarifies my second.